# Driving LED stripes as non-root user

Tags: python, led

I am using python and the Bibliopixel library (https://github.com/ManiacalLabs/BiblioPixel) to drive a strip of LEDs (type LDP8806). For some reasons, I wanne be able to use this w/o using superuser privileges. How must this be configured?

Answer (score 6):

@vertikalist - I'm the developer of BiblioPixel :)

Instead of the sudoers method stated in the other answer (which is still kind of user superuser permissions), I recommend just adding SPI access to the spi port for your user group.

The basics are laid out here: http://forum.maniacallabs.com/showthread.php?tid=27&pid=34#pid34

But the general idea is to do this:

```
usermod -a -G spi pi
```

What this does is add the "pi" user group to the spi access list. This assumes you are using the default "pi" user (yes, the username and group are the same).

After you reboot, you *should* have access to the SPI pins without sudo or su needed.

Feel free to post on the Maniacal Labs forum if you have any other BiblioPixel related questions :)

Answer (score 2):

Adam Heile was very helpful in his answer, thanks.

However, neither the group was existing before, nor the device belonged to a group other than root. One has to

```
sudo groupadd --system spi
sudo adduser pi spi
sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/90-spi.rules
```

and edit the 90-spi.rules to contain this one line:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="spidev", GROUP="spi"
```

then, (after reboot), the user pi can use the spi device directly.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a sudoers entry more details [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/users.md).  Note that you want to make sure you edit this file with visudo this will prevent leaving the file in an inconsistant state and locking you out of your Pi. You will still need super user priviliges but won't need to enter the sudo, and can give it the nopasswd option to avoid being asked for a passwd. Note that this does have negative security implications. Your entry should be added to the end of the file and look something like this

```
myusername ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/executable
```

where myusername is replaced by your username (probably pi)  and the path to executable is the full path to the command you want to run.